# How to prevent "Background items added" notification when running shell script with launch agent

Tags: notifications, launchd, plist, login-items

I created a custom .plist file to run a simple `startup.sh` script when I log into my user, and added it to my `/Library/LaunchAgents` directory. Everything works as intended, however, every time my system starts, I receive multiple notifications with the following contents:

> **Background Items Added**
>
> "startup.sh" is an item that can run in the background. You can manage this in Login Items Settings.

I do not want to see these notifications every time I start my computer. Is it possible to disable them? I am running MacOS 14.3.1.

Here are the contents of my .plist file, if it's relevant:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.startup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/x/startup.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```